# Load Image async for NSTextAttachment for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstextattachment

Loading images dynamically in async thread or image cache library like SDwebimage. Below code is what I tried and it doesn't repaint after image fetched from network.

```
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    if let _img = newsItem.img {
        var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(4, 4, expectedWidth, expectedWidth * _img.ratio)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            attachment.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: _img.src)!)!)
        })

        mutableAttributedString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `image` of `NSTextAttachment` was set, you need to force refreshing of `textView` contents. For that you can use `textView.layoutManager's` method `invalidateDisplayCharacterRange`, where `range` - is the range of your NSTextAttachement substring

Answer (score 1):

@Raniys I am using

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];


                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);


                dispatch_async(queue, ^{


                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [ServerURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/api" withString:@""], iconsArr[i][@"icon"]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];


                    [manager downloadImageWithURL:url options:0 progress:NULL completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {


                        attachment.image = image;


                        [cell.descL setNeedsDisplay];
                    }];
                });


                attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -3, 12, 12);


                NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];


                NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attachmentString];


                NSAttributedString *myText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ \n", iconsArr[i][@"title"]]];


                [myString appendAttributedString:myText];


                [descStr appendAttributedString:myString];
```

Comment: @PrinceiPhone where do you update cell.decl I have issues with threading, the image is not setting.

Comment: not working for tableview cell containt textattachment